# Defining & seeding pseudo-random number generator with global scope (C++)

Tags: c++, random

Is it dangerous/bad form to declare and seed an instance of some RNG (like `std::mt19937`) as a global variable? That way any function call that uses random numbers is essentially synchronized for a given seed. That is, for a given seed, my entire program will run identically. Potential bugs aside, does this also sacrifice any randomness?

Is a better alternative to do declare it in the main() and then just pass the reference to it for any subsequent use in functions?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A global RNG doesn't sacrifice any randomness, but it's like using any other global variable:

- It simplifies the initial implementation.
- It can make future development harder. (E.g., for unit test purposes, maybe you'll want to specify a particular RNG instance with a repeatable sequence.)
- It introduces thread safety concerns. (Two threads accessing a global RNG at the same time becomes a race condition.)

The conventional wisdom is that globals and singletons cause more problems than they solve, but you'll have to decide for yourself how the tradeoffs balance for your program.

Comment: Is there an alternative to global RNGs? For example if I want to use the same seed in multiple functions, should I just declare a new mersenne twister engine and seed it the same way?

Comment: @marcman - If it were me, I'd try and do your suggestion of declaring main() and passing around, as long as that didn't get too cumbersome. (So it's only one instance, but it's shared explicitly rather than implicitly and can easily be changed for unit testing, threading, etc.) Multiple engines with the same seed is also an option, as long as it still gives the reproducibility you want.  (Obviously, calling one RNG instance twice is not the same as calling two RNG instances once.)